# Flash 11.3 class not found on 11.3 player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to include the following class in my Flash project:

```
import flash.display.JPEGXREncoderOptions;
```

According to the [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/JPEGXREncoderOptions.html), this is available as of Flash Player 11.3. I've set up FDT to use `playerglobal.swc` from 11.3 (and indeed, I can see the class inside the SWC from FDT's browser inside my project). This also compiles fine. However, I get the following runtime error when I try to run the output SWF:

```
Error #1014: Class flash.display::JPEGXREncoderOptions could not be found.
```

I've verified that the Flash Player I'm running the .swf with is indeed 11.3 - to be more specific, `11.3.300.265`. I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit, with the debug player.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to set up something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're missing the correct `-swf-version` compiler flag (which you can set in the Debug Configurations and choosing the right compiler flag radio so you can edit the flags as needed)

For example, in Flash Player 11.4 `-swf-version=17`, so I imagine for Flash Player 11.3 it's something like 15 or 16.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that I was passing -swf-version=13 on the run configurations, upping that to 16 did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.
you have 2 options:

1-in property section of every project set **-swf-version=16** in compiler part

2-go to flex sdk folder and find Framework folder next change  following configuarion files:

- air-config
- flex-config
- airmobile-config

  open config files seperatly and change `<target-player>11.3</target-player>`
   and `<swf-version>16</swf-version>`

I suggest to select number 2 because for all project you dont need to manually add compiler parameter

Comment: This question was answered, the answer accepted and all but finished on a week ago. Why would you add an answer that adds no value and activates the question again?